# Starting virtuoso

Tags: linux, debian

I am trying to start virtuoso on Debian 6.0 by issuing the command:

```
/etc/init.d/virtuoso-opensource-6.1 start
```

It fails with the message

> virtuoso-opensource-6.1 disabled,
>   /etc/default/virtuoso-opensource-6.1. ... failed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the file `/etc/default/virtuoso-opensource-6.1` and set `RUN=yes`.

Comment: Please accept your own answer, assuming it answers your original question...